# How to get current year from Version.Build and Version.Revision in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

The following code is to get a copyright year displaying as xxxx - 2020 (or whatever the current year is). It works for every page except WPF pages, any suggestions?

```
    Private Shared Function AssemblyBuildDate(ByVal a As System.Reflection.Assembly) As System.DateTime

        Dim v As System.Version = a.GetName.Version
        Dim dt As System.DateTime

        dt = New System.DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).
            AddDays(v.Build).
            AddSeconds(v.Revision * 2)
        If System.TimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(dt,
            System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(dt.Year)) Then
            dt = dt.AddHours(1)
        End If

        Return dt
    End Function
```

Comment: This can only work if the [AssemblyVersion] is set to auto-increment.  Which is not the default for WPF projects.  Project > Properties > Application tab > Assembly Information button.  The "Assembly version" would have to be set to, say, 1 - 0 - * - blank.  This is not a very good practice.

Comment: We use a visual studio extension: Automatic Versions 2. Our standard is to set the minor version to YYMM and the Build to DD, We can then vary the major as we see fit.